# Why doesn't Javascript/Angular let this function finish before it continues on?

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I have a function within a component that calls a service to get an http response.  In the below method (which calls the service):

```
getSearchResults() {
    let result = this.service.getSearchResults(this.searchValues, this.ITEMSPERPAGE);
    console.log(result);
  }
```

it is going ahead and executing the console.log before the result is even back from the called function.  Why is calling this method (getSearchResults) not a synchronous operation (even though the method being called does asynchronous http action, the return doesn't occur until that's done).  Also, what is the recommended way to handle this so result is back before proceeding?

```
getSearchResults(searchValues, itemsPerPage : number, page : number = 1) {
    let results = {
        studentList: null,
        errorResult: null,
        pages: null,
        totalPages: null
    };
    let searchCriterions = {};
    Object.keys(searchValues).forEach(a => {
      if (searchValues[a] != null && searchValues[a] != '') {
        searchCriterions[a] = searchValues[a];
      }
    }
    );
    searchCriterions['itemsPerPage'] = itemsPerPage.toString();
    searchCriterions['page'] = page;

    this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:8080/data/alumni/search",
      {
        params: searchCriterions
      }).subscribe(data => { 
          results.studentList = data; 


      if (page == 1) {
        this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:8080/data/alumni/search/pageCount",
          {
            params: searchCriterions
          }).subscribe(data => {

            results.pages = Array(Math.ceil(data['pageCount'] / itemsPerPage));
            results.totalPages = results.pages.length;
            console.log(results);
            return results;



          }, error => 
          {
              results.errorResult = error;
              return results;

          });
        } 
        else {
            return results;
        }

        }, error => 
        {
            results.errorResult = error;
            return results;

        });
  }
```

Comment: you should look into how asynchronous functions / observables work. it's not like this. They don't return values, you need to use the subscribe handler / call back to get the value

Comment: Starting a promise won't block the current execution path but just return straight away. Returning from a `then()` callback will just set the return value for the next part of the promise chain. This has been covered a lot of times here on SO already.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript wont stop until API finish so you should use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to get the result only after the API returned/finished. Here is an example:

```
search(term:string) {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}?term=${term}&media=music&limit=20`;
    this.http.get(apiURL)
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        res => { // Success
          console.log(res.json());
          resolve();
        }
      );
  });
  return promise;
}
```